# Excel can not complete this task with available resources

Tags: excel

When I open my workbook, and try to do some work on my excel file, I started to get this error.

[image]

Even though my computer has enough CPU and RAM while I am doing all of this.

[image]

I have a total of 7 worksheets, some data and formulas. It is not very small but it is not that big either. Is there a way to fix this? I use windows 10 and Ms Excel  2010.

Note to Admins: There is a problem with image uploading to stackoverflow recently. Images don't appear.

Comment: Did you try the 64 bit version of excel?

Comment: I don't have 64  bit version. can I convert 32 bit to 64 bit?

Comment: You probably have to reinstall but your licence should work with 64 bit too.

Comment: ok, I will try this. but still I don't understand this problem. When I get this error, I have a lot of unused ram (16 gb) and cpu power (i7). I wanted to include screenshot of task manager, but images don't appear here.

Comment: I quote from MS: "32-bit environment is subject to 2 gigabytes (GB) of virtual address space, shared by Excel, the workbook, and add-ins that run in the same process". https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: Thanks, @meow, apparently i will have to switch to 64 bit version.

Comment: Most probably this is the issue about used range. Do a Ctrl+End on each sheet and identify if the last cell is way far right or far down. You will find lots of unused columns/rows that are marked as used range

Comment: I see. I have column and row lines go to the end of the sheet. I'll change that. Thanks @PankajR

Comment: @Max Delete all those unused rows and columns. You might have to do that in bits and pieces if excel runs into error deleting all. And save file between each delete

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Save the worksheet separately, thus it would not be my fault if something goes wrong :)
- Save the file to `XLSB`
- Take a look at the styles at Excel. If they look a bit strange, e.g., not like this:

[image]

1. Then go to this [Microsoft site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213904/you-receive-a-too-many-different-cell-formats-error-message-in-excel);
2. Read method 3 download & run the RemoveStyles tool;